# How can i affect another div when i hover on link of another one?

Tags: html, css

So, i made a website using Wordpress and elementor, I would like to change the image on the right when you hover on the label 'Carrello'. Basically when I hover on different drop-down menu labels, the ima should change accordingly on which link I'm hovering. That's the link of the website (don't look at anything else, I'm just doing some practice on Mega Menu).
That's my code (in this example I've just used display:none just to see if I can affect the other div but the goal should be change it) :

```
.megamenu22 .elementor-nav-menu li:nth-child(2):hover ~ .elementor-element-d0f1e73 img {display:none !important}
```

Thank you!

```
https://www.archless.it/
```

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: I linked the website, basically when i scroll down the voices under the drop menu of "Carrello" when i hover on the different links the image should change. For instance imagine having a clothes drop down menu, when you hover on tshirts the image on the right should show you an image of a tshirt, when you hover on the voice underwear, on the right the image should change in an underwear one and go on.

Comment: Please check "[How do I ask a good question ?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" and [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)